# npm run build with parcel throws an error

Tags: json, npm

Installed node, ran npm init to create package.json, installed parcel. running the server with npx parcel index.html runs the server. Then I changed "scripts" to "start": "parcel index.html" in package.json, and run npm run start, it also runs the server without a problem. And then I added to "scripts" "build": "parcel build index.html" and run npm run build. But this does not work...
I get the error below...

```
> vjezba-17@1.0.0 build  
> parcel build index.html

× Build failed.

@parcel/namer-default: Target "main" declares an output file path of "index.js" which does not match the compiled bundle type "html".

  C:\Users\ijevr\Desktop\JavaScript\vjezba 17\package.json:4:11
    3 |   "version": "1.0.0",
  > 4 |   "main": "index.js",
  >   |           ^^^^^^^^^^ Did you mean "index.html"?
    5 |   "scripts": {
    6 |     "start": "parcel index.html",

  ℹ Try changing the file extension of "main" in package.json.
```

Of course, changing the main to index.html states that the file should be a .js file... index.js is what the npm init created in the package.json. In my folder, my main js file is named script.js, and it was named like this before I ran npm init. However changing the main to script.js also does not help, I get the same error as stated here...

I don't know what to do to npm build it...

Answer (score 4):

To resolve these issues. Kindly remove the `"main": "index.js",` from the package.json files.

From this *package.json*::

```
 {
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  }
}
```

To this *package.json*::

```
 {
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  }
}
```

https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#package.json%23main

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `main` property from `package.json` completely, or add this to the `package.json`:

```
"targets": {
  "main": false
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a fix, but I found out that with Parcel 2 the build process changed.
Works now.

Script should look like this:

```
"start": "parcel",
"build": "parcel build"
```

and main and source like this:

"main": "dist/index.js", //with dist being the path of the build

"source": "src/script.js", //and src the path of our project

Answer (score 1):

```
The structure of the package.json file should look like this when using the Parcel library

 "targets": {
    "main": false
  }, 
 "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/71708198/20383654
I added the following as suggested and the build worked.
`"targets": { "main":false },`